# DC motor parameter identification using microcontroller

Tags: dc-motor, pid-controller, duty-cycle, rpm

I've built a DC motor controller which measures the speed and current (not really sure yet about current values) of a permanent magnet DC motor. I plan to connect different PM DC motors. Is there a way to build a software routine which identify the motor's characteristics and adjust the parameters of the controller (let's say a PID) according to what is best for that specific motor? When there's enough load, the motor tends to decrease the speed and that's what I want to compensate.

Is it strictly necessary to use MATLAB to identify every motor I plan to connect? I don't have much experience designing PID controllers microcontroller-based. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Since @TonyEErocketscientist already answered the motor testing part, I'll just add on PID part of your question.

> Is there a way to build a software routine which identify the motor's characteristics and adjust the parameters of the controller (let's say a PID) according to what is best for that specific motor?

No, this is **not** possible. Motor characteristics have very little to do with PID control. It is the reaction of entire system (a.k.a. Plant) and the desired PID behavior (response time, stabilization time, overshot etc.) that define control terms.

There are algorithms that can measure the response of the actual system and tune up control loop. However using these algorithms requires the plant to be controllable by software outside of control loop and safe to be driven arbitrary (i.e. often outside normal operational limits). In addition the controllable method for injection of external disturbances might be required.

All of the above is the reason why there are no one-controller-fits-all devices on the market, AFAIK.

Having said that, some devices, like hobby servos, can be tuned for a wide range of the operating conditions. The control loop might not be optimal for specific application but would be "good enough" and indeed will be tightly bound to specific motor characteristics. In this case PID tuning is happening at the design and testing times and fixed before final production begins.

Answer (score 0):

The best design will have a current shunt options for 100 mV max draw at 10x rated current, to represent start current , I=V/DCR of motor coil. Selectable shunts in the < 1 ohm range may be necessary for a wide range of motors using NFETs on the low side or if you can manage a good low noise Diff Amp with selectable gain to 5V max using analog switches.

Then to measure RPM for accurate speed you need some sensor, either a tach, or a type II PLL with a tracking filter to derive the RPM spikes to a 1 shot tach cct.

Max Hp load at rated voltage will be approx. 82 to ideal 84% No load max RPM rated in kRPM/V.

Current feedback average will be your torque feedback and multiplied by RPM gives mechanical power. Of course losses are many TBD that determines efficiency which requires an understanding of rotational kinetic energy and how to measure it, which you did not mention.  One can use a variable shunt resistor using a PWM NFET on a generator  to load a motor, coupled by 8mm belt drive common in mini CNC stores.  The shunt dummy load can be a halogen light bulbs of suitable cold resistance such that the RdsOn of the NFET is much lower for cool operation and is close to matching the power resistance to *brake* or stall the generator by uC control with a sweep of duty cycle.

You can go simple or comprehensive in your motor eval. by adding a temp sensor IC to the motor ,thermally insulated on the outside.